# curl request with arguments from "find" command

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have the bash script which makes pg_dumpall and uploads to my FTP server.

```
#/bin/bash
timeslot=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`
backup_dir="/var/lib/backup"
name=recycle_backup_$timeslot.sql.gz
set -e 

find /var/lib/backup/*.sql.gz -mtime +7 -type f -exec rm -rvf {} \; -exec curl -p --insecure ftp://aaa.bbb/backup/{} --user user:password -Q 'DELE backup/'{} \;

echo $timeslot "Running docker container to backup Postgresql"

sudo docker run --rm \
        -t \
        --name postgres-backup \
        -v "/var/lib/backup":"/mnt" \
        -w "/mnt" \
        -e PGPASSWORD="password" \
        --entrypoint=/usr/bin/pg_dumpall \
        postgres:9 \
        -h 1.2.3.4 -U postgres | gzip -9 > $backup_dir/$name


echo "Your back is successfully stored in " $backup_dir

curl -T /var/lib/backup/$name ftp://aaa.bbb/backup/ --user user:password
```

It cleans up all old .sql.gz files (older than 7 days).

After these steps, the script makes a docker container with Postgres, runs commands to make backup and saves it locally to **/var/lib/backup/filename.sql.gz**.

**The problem** is I can't clean up files on my FTP server with arguments that "**find**" returns.

```
find /var/lib/backup/*.sql.gz -mtime +7 -type f -exec rm -rvf {} \; -exec curl -p --insecure ftp://aaa.bbb/backup/{} --user user:password -Q 'DELE backup/'{} \;
```

How to add the argument {} from find command to this curl request? `-Q 'DELE BACKUP/'{} \;`

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work, you can only use `{}` once with find.

Maybe try this approach? Remove the `echo` if this looks sane ...

```
find /var/lib/backup/*.sql.gz -mtime +7 -type f -exec rm -rvf {} + | awk '{print gensub( /...(.*)/, "\\1","1",$2)}' | while read -s file 
do 
  echo curl -p --insecure ftp://aaa.bbb/backup/{} --user user:password -Q 'DELE backup/'${file}
done
```

Comment: I tried the command below to filter outdated files and print their names, but this doesn't work. find /var/lib/backup/*.sql.gz -mtime +7 -type f -exec echo {} + | awk '{print gensub( /...(.*)/, "\\1","1",$2)}'

Comment: This command cannot find files older than X days and print their pathes

Comment: Right you are. I didn't have any "old files" for testing, so stripped that condition out. Fixing that now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with a second script, which connects to FTP server and deletes outdated files in a loop from this topic [Linux shell script for delete old files from ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203988/linux-shell-script-for-delete-old-files-from-ftp)