# Bash script - delete old files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, debian

I have a script that uploaded a compressed file to an ftp, it is the code that I show below.

This code works correctly, but I would like to adapt it so that once the file is uploaded, it deletes **ftp files** older than a week.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='xxx'
USER='xxx'
PASSWD='xxx'
DAY=`date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M"`

cd /temp
rm -fr backup
mkdir backup
cd backup

 
export GZIP=-9
tar -czvf $DAY-backup.tar.gz  --exclude="*/node_modules/*" /var/www/html/cars


FILE=$DAY-backup.tar.gz

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

Comment: I need to delete files from ftp. thxs

Comment: Then look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203988/linux-shell-script-for-delete-old-files-from-ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
# Purpose: This step is used to Purge 7 days old files
export PROJECT_LOG="${PROJECT_HOME}/log";
export APP_MAINT_LOG="APP.log"
export LOG_RETAIN_DUR=7
echo "Maintenance Job Started" > "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
echo "=========================================================================" >> "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
echo "${LOG_RETAIN_DUR} Day(s) Old Log Files..." >> "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
echo "=========================================================================" >> "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
find "${PROJECT_LOG}" -mtime +"${LOG_RETAIN_DUR}" -type f -exec ls -1 {} \; >> "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
#find "${PROJECT_LOG}" -mtime +"${LOG_RETAIN_DUR}" -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
echo "=========================================================================" >> "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
echo "Maintenance Job Completed" >> "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
cat "${APP_MAINT_LOG}"
```

> **Note:** I have commented the Remove file line, so that you can check and run !

Comment: Please let me know if this example is not useful, so that I will delete my post !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that I need is delete files older than 7 days from the ftp.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a find command to catch file older than 7 days and delete it.
So it give something like this :

```
find . -type f -name ".*-backup.tar.gz" -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

You can add this line in your script
If you want to test first remove replace the exec part by print to display the files catched :

```
find . -type f -name ".*-backup.tar.gz" -mtime +7 -print
```

Comment: Two alternatives to `-exec rm {} \;` are: 1) `-exec rm {} +` to issue one single `rm` instead of spawning one per file. 2) Use `-delete` instead of `-exec ...`. These options may not be available everywhere though.